# Deploy Azure docker container not updating ngix.conf

Tags: azure, nginx, containers

How do I deploy to an Azure container that contains an nginx web and requires URL rewrites (typically put in nginx.conf)?

I have a docker container running nginx that runs fine when deployed to a local container. However when I deploy it to Azure, the nginx.conf file that contains my URL rewrites does not appear to get uploaded.

Looking at the nginx.conf within the Azure container instance, I see an nginx.conf file but it is not mine. The last line in the nginx.conf appears to run ./conf.d/*.conf 
I see a file ./conf.d/default.conf that appears to be a template where the URL redirects should be placed but even when I update this file manually and restart  the container it does not seem to do the redirect.

Appreciate any help on this. Thanks...
Terry

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, you have misunderstood the restart action. When you restart the ACI, then the ACI will be a new one with the same configuration. See [Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-stop-start#restart). You can just restart the nginx service inside the ACI, not restart the ACI itself.

As I know, there are two ways to solve the problem. One is that you create a new image with copying the files which you want to update the nginx into the image. Another one is to use a persistent volume. I will suggest you use the [Azure File Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files). Mount the Azure File Share to your ACI at the path `./conf.d/` and upload the files which you want to update the nginx into the file share.